# Pyexcel random.choice() not quite working how I need it to

Tags: python, excel, loops, if-statement

so how can I loop a function to pull an element at random and if it doesn't meet certain parameters pull a different element?

I'm pretty new to python and honestly coding in general. So let me explain what I'm doing.

The project is basically automating character choice for players one and two. In excel there is a list of characters names, their 'pecking' number, win, lose, ect. I'm using the 'pecking' number to determine what characters are picked.

Each time the program runs it increases all characters pecking number by 1.

It then makes a list of lists that contain all characters names and pecking number.

Then it finds the highest pecking number and places that name as fighter 1. (and picks if there is a tie)

Now (**the part I'm stuck on**)it pulls a list at random and checks that 1) it isn't fighter 1 and 2) that it's pecking number is above a certain value and makes that player 2.(my way of making it a semi deterministic random)

```
def another_one(sequence):
    item = random.choice(sequence)
    if item[0] == fighter_one:
        another_one(sequence)
    elif item[1] < 20:
        another_one(sequence)
    else:
        new_guy = item
        return new_guy
```

If I'm correct it seems that it is pulling the first "item" at random just fine, but at if it hits the "if" or "elif" it just ends? I don't know. any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: ok so I added a print("if fail") and ("elif fail") to see if it was hitting it and it is printing the "elif fail" line twice. So I think its saying once it is run the first time that 'random' element is now permanent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do recursion, but you forgot to return to propagate the result back through the chain of `another_one` calls. So the fix would look like:

```
def another_one(sequence):
    item = random.choice(sequence)
    if item[0] == fighter_one:
        return another_one(sequence)
    elif item[1] < 20:
        return another_one(sequence)
    else:
        new_guy = item
        return new_guy
```

But if all you're checking for is those conditions, maybe recursion isn't needed. A loop is clearer and won't run into recursion limits. This is what the equivalent loop looks like:

```
def another_one(sequence):
    while True: # return will exit an infinite loop
        item = random.choice(sequence)
        if item[0] != fighter_one and item[1] >= 20:
            new_guy = item
            return new_guy
```

Of course both cases assume `sequence` does contain the fighter you're looking for. If it doesn't, the recursion will run in circles until hitting the recursion limit, and the loop will run in circles forever.

So personally I would've iterated through sequence making sure there are fighters that fit, then randomly selected from those:

```
# fighter_one and min_value are arguments because I don't like global variables
def another_one(sequence, fighter_one, min_value = 20):
    candidates = []
    
    for item in sequence:
        if item[0] != fighter_one and item[1] >= min_value:
            candidates.append(item)
        
    if len(candidates) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return random.choice(candidates)
```

Comment: awesome! i knew it was gonna be something simple like that but for the life of me i couldn't get it.

Comment: Also yeah I do like your choice to iterate it. I have another function that adds 1 to the pecking so I could have it run that in the "if len()" part then return the "another_one" function to make sure it always pulls a fighter.